# jQuery File tree from remote Server

Tags: jquery, ssh, paramiko, remote-server, filetree

I am implementing a file tree in my website that fetches directory information over a remote source *(ssh user@remote).*

Currently my web page looks like this. The file tree is supposed to be in the left marked panel.

[image]

I have used the ***paramiko*** library to fetch the current list of directories. 
However, I wish to display the directory information in a nice tree view format, like normal file explorers usually do.

Is there a jQuery file manager that incorporates the remote aspect? I don't wish to write an entire file tree from scratch because ***DRY***

I have looked over [jQuery file tree](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree) but it fails to achieve the remote purpose.

Any leads would be great.

Comment: What do you want? A library that do the all work for you? There is no such library like that...

Comment: Not to mention the animosity of your comment, it turns out that there did exist a library that solves exactly this. It is called "Fancy Tree". Today you learnt ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone stumbles upon this, I finally solved it using [Fancy Tree Library](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) that has a parameter source, which I can then refer to my AJAX :)

`$(#fancytree).fancytree({
source: {
        url: "refreshDirectory"
    }});`